# Kali Linux crashes when connecting an Android device

Tags: kali-linux, usb, android, crash

For some reason whenever I connect any android device using any USB cable to any of my ports on Kali Linux, the screen goes black for a second before going to the login screen. Then if I log in and the device is still connected it will just crash again. All running programs are stopped.

I have no idea whats causing this behavior, before I had no problems connecting my devices and this just started happening one day. Does anyone know what might cause this and what I can do about it?

Comment: @John compeletly different question

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419709/kali-linux-logging-off-when-pluging-usb-device

Comment: You are using Kali to pen-test your Android device? Or why do you want to connect one to it? (Kali Linux is not for daily work, as the "possible duplicate" link explains in detail. If you want to use Kali for daily work, you are doing it wrong - Kali is an intentionally hacked-up distro which will easily crash when you try to do things not in its scope. So use another distro designed for daily work.).

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you may not be right using kali that way.

But, you said that your computer crash (?) or just the graphic side is crashing just go to another TTY with CTRL+ALT+F3 type this command :

dmesg -w

plug the android device and see what happens, that command could give you information about the problem.